# Typescript reducer initial state and option argument for react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-reducer

I have a type for my reducer such as:

```
export type Style = {
  color: string;
  (rest...)
}

export const initialState: Style = {
  color: 'blue';
  (rest...)
}
```

I have a component that takes in a style object and the properties are optional and simply overwrites the current state of the style. The type looks like this:

```
export type InputStyle = {
  color?: string;
  (rest?...)
}
```

So I basically have to create two duplicate types, except one has all optional properties, and one doesn't. Is there a better pattern for this? My intuition says this is not the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`Partial` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialt) - might be exactly what you're looking for:

```
export type Style = {
  color: string;
  (rest...)
}

export type InputStyle = Partial<Style>;
```